# Dialogs must be user-initiated. Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have read almost all SO threads about this error. What i found is that Openfiledialog must be the first line of Button Click Handler in code behind file of your view.

I have done this but still i got this error on random.

```
Dialogs must be user-initiated.

at System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
at Portal.Presentation.SL.Views.AddEditPatient.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

any pointers?
I am using silverlight 4

Regards.

Comment: Think the check is actually based on a timer rather than the call stack, which could explain why this is an intermittent failure. Maybe something else is a little slow, is another event handler firing first on this click?

Comment: No other code is fired. just the first line of code is OpenFileDialog. but you are right i got this error reported by QA when they do functional testing and click that button very frequently in a short time span. what should i do to avoid this. how can i control that delay?

Comment: You won't be able to control the delay, that's Silverlight internals (and would circumvent the 'security' issue that gives rise to the restriction), but maybe you need to disable the dialog while already starting to show the dialog? If it's actually being clicked again before the dialog is shown.

Comment: Sorry i did not clarified the problem properly. this is not the case to open multiple dialogs by clicking the button frequently but to open and close the dialog very fast. "clicking the button and press escape and again clicking".

Comment: Sounds like you need to disable the button when they click it and don't enable it until the close code has finished executing.

Comment: thanks @Bryant seems like this is the only way.. i don't know why did MS use timer for this.. it exhibit random behavior.. if you can post an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Dialogs must be user-initiated." with SaveFileDialog in Silverlight 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355078/dialogs-must-be-user-initiated-with-savefiledialog-in-silverlight-3)