# Dialogs must be user-initiated exception after user click

Tags: c#, silverlight, openfiledialog

I have the following code and am still experiencing a "Dialogs must be user-initiated" exception on the ofd.ShowDialog();

```
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES;
        ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
        ofd.Multiselect = false;
        bool? userClickedOK = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {.....}
    }
```

From MSDN:

> In addition, there is a limit on the time allowed between when the user initiates the dialog and when the dialog is shown. If the time limit between these actions is exceeded, an exception will occur.

I can't see how the few lines after the click event is taking up this time limit.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand why are you assigning `ShowDialog()` result to a nullable bool type object and then checking it against `true`.

Comment: Following some tutorials found online, such as was done in http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx Don't think this is causing the issue as I just changed it to if(ofd.ShowDialog() == true) and got the same exception

Comment: Above should be `ofd.ShowDialog().Value == true`.. Same result though.

Comment: Do you call `btnOpen_Click` directly from the Button Click event?

Comment: Yeh it is tied to the click using `this.btnOpen.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnOpen_Click);` in the loaded event of the control

Comment: Ok, strange - that should work correctly. As a side note: I can't think of any situation when hooking up the event handlers onLoaded is the correct point in time. When inside a UserControl you can do so in the constructor or in xaml. When inside a templated control during OnApplyTemplate. But I don't think it is related to the issues you are currently facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this. 
The Loaded event is being subscribed to in the constructor, and while the constructor is called just once for the control, the loaded even is being called twice and hence the `btnOpen_Click` event is being subscribed to twice. 
I can fix it by unsubscribing from the loaded event in the control unloaded event but I'm still not sure why the Loaded is being called twice.

Comment: Why do you use the `Loaded` event? Is it inside a templated control?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, have not tested this myself but maybe I found a hint in a quite similar SO question/answer:

```
private OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog {get;set;}

public Ctor()
{
    OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
}

private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ... OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    ...
}
```

Instantiate the dialog in the `constructor` and only call the `ShowDialog` method inside your button click handler without instantiating a new dialog.

[Edit]
That's the [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105197/dialogs-must-be-user-initiated-silverlight?rq=1) I mentioned.