# Export to Excel in silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight

I use the following code for export to excel,it works fine,but how can I change it to xport directly to .xlsx file not xml file,also I do not want to use automation because it works very slow.

Thanks.

```
public static class DataGridxtensions
{
  public static void Export(this DataGrid dg)
  {
    ExportDataGrid(dg);
  }

  public static void ExportDataGrid(DataGrid dGrid)
  {    
    SaveFileDialog objSFD = new SaveFileDialog() { DefaultExt = "xml", Filter = "Excel XML (*.xml)|*.xml", FilterIndex = 1 };

    if (objSFD.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
      string strFormat = objSFD.SafeFileName.Substring(objSFD.SafeFileName.IndexOf('.') + 1).ToUpper();
      StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      if (dGrid.ItemsSource == null) return;
      List<string> lstFields = new List<string>();

      if (dGrid.HeadersVisibility == DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column || dGrid.HeadersVisibility == DataGridHeadersVisibility.All)
      {
        foreach (DataGridColumn dgcol in dGrid.Columns)
          lstFields.Add(FormatField(dgcol.Header.ToString(), strFormat, false));
        BuildStringOfRow(strBuilder, lstFields, strFormat);
      }

      foreach (object data in dGrid.ItemsSource)
      {
        lstFields.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridColumn col in dGrid.Columns)
        {
          string strValue = "";
          Binding objBinding = null;

          if (col is DataGridBoundColumn)
            objBinding = (col as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding;

          if (col is DataGridTemplateColumn)
          {
            //This is a template column... let us see the underlying dependency object
            DependencyObject objDO = (col as DataGridTemplateColumn).CellTemplate.LoadContent();
            FrameworkElement oFE = (FrameworkElement)objDO;
            FieldInfo oFI = oFE.GetType().GetField("TextProperty");

            if (oFI != null)
            {
              if (oFI.GetValue(null) != null)
              {
                if (oFE.GetBindingExpression((DependencyProperty)oFI.GetValue(null)) != null)
                  objBinding = oFE.GetBindingExpression((DependencyProperty)oFI.GetValue(null)).ParentBinding;
              }
            }
          }

          if (objBinding != null)
          {
            if (objBinding.Path.Path != "")
            {
              PropertyInfo pi = data.GetType().GetProperty(objBinding.Path.Path);
              if (pi != null) strValue = pi.GetValue(data, null).ToString();
            }

            if (objBinding.Converter != null)
            {
              if (strValue != "")
                strValue = objBinding.Converter.Convert(strValue, typeof(string), objBinding.ConverterParameter, objBinding.ConverterCulture).ToString();
              else
                strValue = objBinding.Converter.Convert(data, typeof(string), objBinding.ConverterParameter, objBinding.ConverterCulture).ToString();
            }
          }

          lstFields.Add(FormatField(strValue, strFormat, true));
        }

        BuildStringOfRow(strBuilder, lstFields, strFormat);
      }

      StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(objSFD.OpenFile());
      if (strFormat == "XML")
      {
        //Let us write the headers for the Excel XML
        sw.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        sw.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
        sw.WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
        sw.WriteLine("<DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">");
        sw.WriteLine("<Author>Arasu Elango</Author>");
        sw.WriteLine("<Created>" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongDateString() + "</Created>");
        sw.WriteLine("<LastSaved>" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongDateString() + "</LastSaved>");
        sw.WriteLine("<Company>Atom8 IT Solutions (P) Ltd.,</Company>");
        sw.WriteLine("<Version>12.00</Version>");
        sw.WriteLine("</DocumentProperties>");
        sw.WriteLine("<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Export\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
        sw.WriteLine("<Table>");
      }

      sw.Write(strBuilder.ToString());

      if (strFormat == "XML")
      {
        sw.WriteLine("</Table>");
        sw.WriteLine("</Worksheet>");
        sw.WriteLine("</Workbook>");
      }

      sw.Close();
    }
  }

  private static void BuildStringOfRow(StringBuilder strBuilder, List<string> lstFields, string strFormat)
  {
    switch (strFormat)
    {
      case "XML":
        strBuilder.AppendLine("<Row>");
        strBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join("\r\n", lstFields.ToArray()));
        strBuilder.AppendLine("</Row>");
        break;
      case "CSV":
        strBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", lstFields.ToArray()));
        break;
    }
  }

  private static string FormatField(string data, string format, bool isNumber)
  {
    switch (format)
    {
      case "XML":

        if (isNumber)
        {
          return String.Format("<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">{0}</Data></Cell>", data);
        }
        else
        {
          return String.Format("<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">{0}</Data></Cell>", data);
        }
      case "CSV":
        return String.Format("\"{0}\"", data.Replace("\"", "\"\"\"").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

First, there are several component vendors who have solved this problem. There's [SyncFusion's XlsIo](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/silverlight/xlsio), and [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/damyan_petev/archive/2012/05/23/infragistics-xaml-excel-engine-new-features.aspx), and [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/Exporting) (looks like they have .xls only).

If the financial cost is too high, then you might consider [OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). The learning curve would be a bit steeper, and you can't use it directly from Silverlight -- you'd have to make the server convert your data to an .xlsx file and then your client would save the results. Also, you'll need to be aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355078/dialogs-must-be-user-initiated-with-savefiledialog-in-silverlight-3).

But, it is free. I have had some success reading Excel files with it. I think this might be the [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) you'd need, or you can download an [installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

Fortunately for me, my employer paid for the first option above when we needed to create an .xlsx file. :-)

Comment: I do not want to use those component, also I do not want to use automation way, because it works slow, is there a way that I can change my code for export directly to xlsx or xls file?

Answer (score 0):

Yup office Automation way to slow! I had to change to, I used code from

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45731/Export-Silverlight-DataGrid-to-Excel-XML-CSV?msg=4829021#xx4829021xx